# Как в Java найти одинаковые элементы в массиве и вывести их?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, java

Буду благодарен за алгоритм решения данной задачи на Java.
Причём должен выводится в таком виде: совпадение n в позиции x.

Comment: @webcom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если массив сложных элементов (например, ваш собственный класс), переопределите в нем метод `hashCode()` так, чтобы он с высокой вероятностью работал без коллизий.

Далее действуйте уже, как требует задача: если элементов в массиве не слишком много - переберите элементы в двойном цикле. Если слишком много - поищите подходящий алгоритм.

Comment: Но разве не разумнее будет переопределить метод equals, тем самым исключая коллизии вообще?

Comment: @nekanenka, обычно, когда речь идет о hashCode(), подразумевается и equals(). Это так очевидно, что я решил просто не упоминать об этом.

Comment: Но ведь hashCode и equals это совершенно разные фунции, вот интересная статья на тему http://habrahabr.ru/post/168195/

Comment: @nekaneka, правда разные? Хм, да нет, что вы, они одинаковые!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void arrayCheck(int[] array){
        HashSet<Integer> used = new HashSet<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(used.contains(array[i])){
                continue;
            } else {
                used.add(array[i]);
            }
            ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
            positions.add(i);
            for(int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++){

                if(array[i] == array[j]){
                    positions.add(j);
                }
            }
            System.out.print(array[i] + " встречается в позициях " );
            for(Integer p : positions){
                System.out.print(p + ", ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но у меня выдаёт ошибку: Отсутствует главный метод класса : "test.FinfElement". Скажу сразу, что Java только начал изучать. Прошу не судить строго за явные ошибки :)

Comment: Ну, ошибка явно не в этом коде. У класса должен быть метод main, с которого все стартует. Оттуда можно считать массив или создать статически, а затем вызвать метод, передав туда массив.

Comment: А как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну, тут самостоятельно нужно.

Comment: Сделал :) Спасибо за совет.